# Google Service Account no longer has access to Calendar API

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-calendar-api, google-api-java-client, google-workspace

I had a react app working perfectly using gapi-script to retrieve Google Calendar events. It was working until recently. Now I get a 404 "Not Found" error when trying to authenticate. I assume something may have changed in the API or authentication settings (note: this is a G Suite account).

I have a service account set up with domain-wide deligation and an API key with the appropriate website and API restrictions.

I also went into the Admin console and was sure that all scopes are added for the calendar.

I noticed when double-checking the shared calendar settings, the "Make changes to events" option is disabled for the service account address.

Any help would be amazing! Thank you!

Comment: Perhaps, as a long shot, your problem has some kind of relation with mine: today I get an "Unreachable Service: mirror" error when I try to run any function from a gscript that uses the Google Classroom API. My script worked before migrating to the Chrome V8 runtime and after that as well. I opened an issue here in Stack Overflow: "Google Apps Script: “Unreachable Service: mirror” error" in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61675511/google-apps-script-unreachable-service-mirror-error.

Answer (score 0):

Since you posses a *G Suite account*, I suggest you to contact **G Suite support** instead.

You can simply contact them by accessing this link [here](https://support.google.com/a/answer/1047213?hl=en) and by choosing the most convenient option for you.

Comment: And as it is explained in the "Scope of G Suite support" of your link, for Google Apps Script "we [G Suite support] use the popular programming Q&A website Stack Overflow to field technical questions. The site is not run by Google, but you can sign in using your Google account. Stack Overflow contains questions on a variety of topics, and developers use the tag [google-apps-script] to mark questions relevant to this service. You may wish add additional tags to your question to attract the attention of experts in related technologies.". So, this is the right place.

Comment: @LaosLos, as described by the user, their question is related to Calendar API **not** Apps Script. Cheers!

Comment: And again, in "Scope of Support" says "Support for Google APIs is provided on Stack Overflow. To find the Stack Overflow forum you need, refer to the links at the bottom of the G Suite API site."

Comment: The question seems related to their **particular** G Suite account here, which is why the G Suite support link has been recommened. @LaosLos